# Component not emitting value back to parent component

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I've got a problem with one of my components, the issue is that it doesn't seem to emit the model when the model changes. It works for my other components just fine but with this one it doesn't work no matter what I do.

The select component:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, DoCheck} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-select',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-select/form-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-select/form-select.component.css'],
  inputs: [
    'options',
    'callback',
    'model',
    'modelProperty',
    'optionProperty',
    'disabled',
    'allowEmpty',
    'label'
  ]
})

export class FormSelectComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() model: any;
  @Output() onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private isOpen: boolean = false;
  private previousModel: any = null;

  ngOnInit() {

    // If no model is set and the select shouldn't be allowed empty, set the model to the first option
    if (!this.model && !this.allowEmpty) {
      this.model = this.options[0];
    }
    // If it should be allowed empty, set it to null which will add an empty class in the markup
    else if (this.allowEmpty) {
      this.model = null;
    }
  }

  ngDoCheck() {

    // Check if the model changes and emit it if it does
    if (this.previousModel !== this.model) {
      this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);
    }

    this.previousModel = this.model;
  }

  toggle() {

    if (this.disabled) {
      this.isOpen = false;

      return false;
    }

    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  close() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  select(option) {
    this.model = option;
    this.close();

    this.callback ? this.callback() : false;
  }

  isSelected(option) {
    return option[this.modelProperty] === this.model[this.modelProperty];
  }
}
```

When I check the value with `pre` the value stays the same despite the model changing inside the component:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 m-b-xxs">
  <pre>{{user.country}}</pre>
  <form-select [(model)]="user.country" modelProperty="country" [options]="countries" optionProperty="country" label="Country"></form-select>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a redundant `on`

```
@Output() onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

should be

```
@Output() modelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

For the shorthand two-way-binding syntax `[(...)]` the names of the properties (input and output) need to be identical except the `Change` suffix for the output.

Comment: but that's just a name..? it doesn't work the other way either.

Comment: This is odd.. just tried it again and it worked. I had it like `modelChange` from the start but thought that onModelChange sounded better, where can I find information about this?

Comment: It's not just a name. The name is significant. See my updated answer. If you don't want this restriction to be forced on the property names of your class you can pass the name to the decorators like `@Input('model') myModel;` and `@Output('modelChange') fancyName;`

Comment: But in other components I have an input called `onLogin` for example and then the output `onLogin`, and that still emits a value. This is a function however so maybe the same rules doesn't apply. So why exactly do I need the `Change` suffix?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel mentions it (serach for ``xChange` within the page). You can name the output like you want when you bind to it like `(onLogin)="doSomething"` but when you use the combined form for two-way-binding `[(xxx)]="yyy"` then you need to follow this rule.

Comment: Do you have to do something specific when emitting an array? Because I have a similar select box but that one emits an array, which uses the same thing with model and modelChange but that one doesn't work.

Comment: Angular doesn't check changes within objects and array. If you emit the same array instance as before even with modified content, Angular change detection doesn't notify this.

Comment: Bummer.. Is there an easy workaround? If you need me to post another question about this I will but gonna have to wait like an hour..

Comment: You can use `this.someArrayProperty = this.someArrayProperty.slice(); this.someArrayPropertyChange.emit(this.someArrayProperty);`

Comment: Need it to be the same instance though since I pass the model to other components as well.. I'll just post a new question.